# Java Platformer: Player Jumps Through Platform

Tags: java, awt, collision-detection

So, I'm nearing the end of making a simple Java platformer but there's one big problem left, when the player jumps and collides with the platform from below, the player sometimes (and always if they're close to the platform) jumps through the platform and lands on the one above. Here is the code:

```
package Main;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Platformer extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    // buffering variables
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    // running boolean
    private boolean running = true;

    // Player coords
    private int rectX = 100;
    private int rectY = 420;

    // initialise dx and dy at zero
    private double dx = 0;
    private double dy = 0;

    private boolean jumping = false;

    //debug Strings
    private String inter = new String();
    private String coords = new String();
    private String debugX = "", debugY = "";

    //for moving the player
    private int worldShift = 0;

    //sprites
    Rectangle2D player = new Rectangle2D.Double();// = new Rectangle2D.Double(rectX, rectY, 10, 10);
    Rectangle2D ground = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 420, 800, 150);
    int[][] platforms = { {300, 300, 100, 20}, { 450, 200, 100, 20 }, 
            { 500, 250, 100, 20 }, { 100, 200, 100, 20 }, { 600, 300, 100, 20 } };
    ArrayList<Rectangle2D> platformList = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();

    int level = 1;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        setSize(800, 480);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++){
            // platforms
            Rectangle2D platform = new Rectangle2D.Double();
            platform.setRect(platforms[i][0] + worldShift, platforms[i][1],
                    platforms[i][2], platforms[i][3]);
            platformList.add(platform);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //Double Buffering
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g2.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    // Paint objects
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        //draw platforms
        if (level == 1) {
            g2.setColor(Color.blue);
            g2.draw(ground);
            g2.fill(ground);

            for (Rectangle2D plat : platformList){
                g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.draw(plat);
                g2.fill(plat);
            }

        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        //debug printouts   
        g.drawString(inter, 400, 30);
        g.drawString(coords, 20, 150);

        //draw player
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.draw(player);
        g2.fill(player);

        //print debug info to screen
        Font bold = new Font("Liberation Sans", Font.BOLD, 36);
        setFont(bold);
        g.drawString("dx, dy: (" + dx + ", " + dy + ")", 30, 30);
        g.drawString("x, y: (" + player.getX() + ", " + player.getY() + ")",
                30, 60);
        g.drawString("" + debugX + ", " + debugY + "", rectX, rectY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {

            update();
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {      
        rectX += dx;
        rectY += dy + 1;

        // stops player running off screen
        if (rectX < 1)  rectX = 0;
        if (rectX > 790) rectX = 790;

        // set sprite coords
        player.setRect(rectX, rectY, 10, 10);
        ground.setRect(0, 420, 800, 480);

        // collision detection
        if (player.intersects(ground)) {
            rectY = (int) (ground.getY() - player.getHeight());
            jumping = false;
            dy = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < platformList.size(); i++){
            Rectangle2D plat = platformList.get(i);
            //sets platform's coordinates
            plat.setRect(plat.getX() + worldShift, plat.getY(), plat.getWidth(), plat.getHeight());
            //sets debug Strings
            coords = "Not on platform";
            inter = " " + platformList.get(0).getX() + worldShift + ", " + worldShift;

            debugX = "" + rectX;
            debugY = "" + rectY;

            //for scrolling the background
            if (rectX > 700 && dx == 5){
                worldShift = -5;}
            else if (rectX < 100 && dx == -5){
                worldShift = 5;}
            else worldShift = 0;

            //collision detection
            if (player.intersects(plat)) {
                jumping = false;
                dy = 0;
                coords = " " + plat.getBounds();
                //if falling
                if (rectY <= (int) (plat.getY() + (plat.getHeight()/2))){
                    rectY = (int) (plat.getY() - player.getHeight());
                //if jumping
                else if (rectY >= plat.getY() + (plat.getHeight()/2)){
                    rectY = (int) (plat.getY() + plat.getHeight());}
                break;
            }
            else if (!player.intersects(plat) && !player.intersects(ground)) {
                jumping = true;
            }
        }

        //implements falling
        if (jumping)
            dy += 1;    
    }

    //button presses
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key pressed code=" + e.getKeyCode() + ", char=" + e.getKeyChar());
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37)
            dx -= 5; // 37 is left
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39)
            dx += 5; // 39 is right
        // if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) dy -= 5; //40 is down
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38 && jumping == false){
            // if on the ground,
            // i.e. only jump if on the ground
            // 38 is up
            dy -= 20;
            jumping = true;
        }
    }

    //key release
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37)
            dx = 0; // 37 is left
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39)
            dx = 0; // 39 is right
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40)
            dy = 0; // 40 is down
        // if (e.getKeyCode() == 38)
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I'm confident there's nothing wrong with the '//collision detection' part of `update()`, but I don't know what the issue is. Amongst other things, I tried placing the jump mechanism in the update loop but it didn't work either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nice "game", I have spent more time with playing then testing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at jump size, it is 20:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key pressed code=" + e.getKeyCode() + ", char=" + e.getKeyChar());
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 37)
        dx -= 5; // 37 is left
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 39)
        dx += 5; // 39 is right
    // if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) dy -= 5; //40 is down
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 38 && jumping == false){
        // if on the ground,
        // i.e. only jump if on the ground
        // 38 is up
        dy -= 20; // <- jump size 20
        jumping = true;
    }
}
```

But your platform height is also `20` and you are deciding by center of platform, it means it just 10 pixels to get above center, jump size should be less then half height of the platform

**EDIT** good configuration:

Try this configuration:

Set increment falling to `+0.25` and jump increment to `-9`

*removed comments to make it shorter*

```
if (jumping)
    dy += 0.25;
```

and

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 37)
        dx -= 5; // 37 is left
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 39)
        dx += 5; // 39 is right
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 38 && jumping == false){
        dy -= 9; // <- jump size set to 9 (half is 10)
        jumping = true;
    }
}
```

Note: the **blinking is terrible**, I have solved it renaming `paint(Graphics)` method to `update(Graphics)`

Comment: Is there a way to solve the problem while maintaing a large jump height?

Comment: It will stay when you decrease the increment of jump to `+0.25`. you cant have jump step higher than a half of the platform, because you can in one step jump higher than is the middle of the platform. your code evaluates you are falling to the platform and puts you on top @foopydoop

Comment: Thank you. And thank you about the blinking, I would have had to figure that out eventually too.